# Moving an image randomly from outside of the screen to the center

Tags: jquery, css, image

I've been stuck on this issue for too long. I need to move an image of a flying cat from random positions OUTSIDE of the screen to appear at the center after which a speech bubble appears and then this cat goes away to a random position outside of the screen. All of this happens Onclick.

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Positioned how? where?

Comment: well, this is the link- http://codepen.io/sofiyashakeel/pen/YGdNwb

Comment: basically the image needs to move from random positions not visible to the user(Outside the screen) and appear right at the center and stay there for a few seconds(delay). After this delay it has to move randomly back to where its not visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the cat is positioned absolutely off screen

jQuery

```
$('#element').click(function(){
  var catWidth = $('.cat').width()/2,
  catHeight = $('.cat').height()/2,
  left = 'calc(50% - '+catWidth+'px)',
  top = 'calc(50% - '+catHeight+'px)';

  $('.cat').css('left', left);
  $('.cat').css('top', top);

));
```

CSS

```
.cat {
    transition: all 2s;
    position: absolute;
    left: 101%;
    top: 101%;
}
```

Put this js within your click function of what ever you wanted to click and this will move the img to the center of the screen.

Comment: It is not encouraged that members should help users that have displayed no effort at solving their own problem. Doing so encourages such laziness by themselves and others in the future.

Comment: You're absolutely right but I have just begun my journey and wouldn't mind some help really. Thank You! :)

Comment: its no full solution but , learn about this: $(".button").click(function() {
 $(".cat").animate({left:1400},500).delay( 1000 ).animate({left:-100},500);
})

Comment: okay so I found another alternative to get the image to the center and that is by moving the image to the point where the mouse is clicked so technically its going to be near the button. $(document).click(function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX,
    y = event.pageY;
                   
    $('.cat').animate({
        top: y - 36,
        left: x - 36
    }, 500);
});

Comment: but I still have to figure out how to make the image move from any random direction outside the container.